# PHP Sum status column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that I am attempting to sum up the status types into variables. For example when I do the following:

```
echo $val['status'];
```

I get:

> New New New Dead In Process New New New New New Dead New Dead Dead New New New In Process

What I am wanting to do is sum all of these up by status type and place them into variables:

```
$statusnew
$statusdead
$statusinprocess
```

so if I were to do an:

```
echo $statusnew;
```

I would be presented with "12" and so forth and so on. I am extremely new to PHP so I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this. I know there is an array_sum function but not sure it will work here since we are not summing numeric values.

Loop:

```
if($_SESSION['partner'] == 1)
{


 $query = "select l.id as lead_id , l.account_name as account_name , l.first_name as first_name , l.last_name as last_name,l.date_entered as date_entered ,  lc.endpoints_c as endpoints ,  l.status as status from leads  as l
                    join leads_cstm  as lc on lc.id_c = l.id                        
                    where lc.account_id_c = '".$_SESSION['account_id']."'
                    and l.deleted = '0' and l.status <> 'Converted' order by date_entered DESC";


 $db -> PS_Pagination($query, 20, 5, "");
 $db -> setDebug(true);
 $rs = $db->paginate();
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
```

further down in the script:

```
        while($val = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
        {
             $date_create = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($val['date_entered']));
```

What I just added from @Joseph:

```
        $count = array(); // for graph

    // then, in your loop:
    if ( array_key_exists($val['status'], $count) )
    $count[$val['status']]++;
    else
    $count[$val['status']] = 1;

    echo $count['New'];
```

Comment: is there a loop in there somewhere? what's the source of the values?

Comment: I have: while($val = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) and: 
 $db -> PS_Pagination($query, 20, 5, "");
 $db -> setDebug(true);
 $rs = $db->paginate();

        
    
   ?>

Comment: since the rows are in a db, why don't you use mysql to return the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$count = array();

while($val = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
{
    $date_create = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($val['date_entered']));

    if ( array_key_exists($val['status'], $count) )
        $count[$val['status']]++;
    else
        $count[$val['status']] = 1;

    // continue with everything else being done in this loop
}
```

After running your loop, you can access the count like this:

```
$count['new']; // 12
$count['dead']; // 4
$count['in proccess']; // 2
```

Comment: where do I define here what new, dead and in process are and which variable to assign them?

Comment: @ipengineer: You access them through their array keys. See my updated answer.

Comment: when I implement and echo $count['New']; I am returned: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 How do I get these totaled up?

Comment: I have upaded the original question with the loop I believe.

Comment: The only reference I see of it is here:
$val = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs) and then when it is inserted into an html table  <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:95px;">&nbsp;
          <?=$val['status']?></Td>

Comment: @ipengineer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2870/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-ipengineer)